# Modeling the shift types in Staff schedulling with linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, lpsolve

So i want to solve problem ,that looks like nurse scheduling Problem, the different is that there is 2 type of Workers, who should work minimum 40 hours per week, the other type should work minimum 10 hours per week. 
In order to solve this problem with simplex , i have to define the shifts(shift types). the shifts in a day should be minimum 3 hours and maximum 9 hours.
 this photo is what i have tried so far[Shifts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie9GC.jpg)

And total of shift types would be 55. and if i multiply that to the number of workers and days. that would be 15000 variables. is it possible to solve a problem like this, or should i try to do it other way? 
Has anyone suggestion?

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nurse example at `CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl\nurses`.

To do what you need you need to change

```
//global max worked time
 forall(n in Nurses)
   ctNurseMaxTimeConstraints: 
     NurseWorkTime[n] <= MaxWorkTime;
```

into

```
 forall(n in Nurses)
   ctNurseMaxTimeConstraints: 
     NurseWorkTime[n] <= n.MaxWorkTime;
```

where maxWorkTime is not global but per nurse. 15000 binary decision variables should be fine.